# UITabBar background behavior

Tags: ios, uitabbar

I'm trying to set an background to my UITabBar but I do not really understand the behavior of it? I thought that it was similar like the UINavigationBar.

**I've set the appearance in my AppDelegate:**

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"backgroundtab.png"]];
```

And `backgroundtab.png`is 98 px hight. I have read some designing help cheats and they say it needs to be this height. But when I start the app, the background is really actually 98 px and get above my TabBar.

Why can't I set the background like my UINavigationBar with imageNamed, or do I need to use the `image assets` file for handeling the TabBar background/icons ?

Kind Regards

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can check the UITabBar height by doing sometime like this:

```
NSLog(@"Height: %i", self.tabbar.bounds.size.height");
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Figured it out